# How to select day 1 to last day in order for me to get dayname of all the days?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @variable1 = (SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY('2016-03-01')) as lastday);
SELECT @variable1 as last_day,
    DAYNAME(CONCAT('2016-03-',@variable1)) as day_name;
```

I am able to get the count of days which is 31 days for march, but how could I get from 1 to 31 the dayname?

in which select statement would show somehow like this:

```
dayname | day count
tuesday      01
wednesday    02
....          ...
thursday      31
```

Comment: Don't know what is your use case, but database should be used to store data not to generate it.

Comment: this is so that i could be able to display all the dayname of the month using angularJS, so i have to make a dynamic way to populate the column of dayname. this is for a DTR system, this could actually be designed better but I am just an employee. hehe. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary table, then do a loop to insert needed data

```
  while @day < @last_day_of_month do
    "insert dayname and day of month into temporary table";
    set @day=@day+1;
  end while;
```

And then select * from "the temporary table"